# How to test receiving a Stripe webhook using ngrok

Tags: meteor, ngrok

I can successfully send a web hook from Stripe to my Meteor app in development using ngrok. For example, my test endpoint on the Stripe dashboard would be sent to something like  https://f5f62fdf.ngrok.io. It responds with a successful notice. The ngrok inspector shows the stripe test object received. But in Meteor I'm a little unsure how the router should look with ngrok. On the server, my route would be something like:

```
Router.route( "<unsure what path to put here>", function() {
  console.log('hello');
}, { where: "server" });
```

In my testing environment using ngrok, what would the path be?

Just trying to get the function to console.log() my 'hello' so I know it's working.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'm an idiot. It console.logs to the terminal, not the browser. Ouch. Given I'm working with Node, it makes sense. Just for posterity, the Stripe endpoint would be something like https://g4r62fdf.ngrok.io/stripe/webhook.

Make sure you're returning a response inside the function so the web hook won't timeout.

```
this.response.statusCode = 200;
this.response.end('10-4, good buddy');
```